# JMeter 5.4.1 Cookie Manager - User-Defined Cookie not added to request's cookies

Tags: cookies, jmeter, cookiemanager

Firstly, I did add the line `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` to `jmeter.properties`.

## What I'm Trying to Do

I want to add a cookie to a request's existing cookies.

For example, I see the request has [edited]:

```
Cookie Data:
c1=sfasfsfsfsfs; c2=erqwerqwrr; c3=poiuopiupoi
```

## Expected Results

I would like it to have:

```
Cookie Data:
c1=sfasfsfsfsfs; c2=erqwerqwrr; c3=poiuopiupoi; partner=favicon.ico
```

Here is what I tried:
[image]

`BASE_URL_2` is a variable defined in the form `qa.company.com`.

## Actual Results

Whatever I have tried so far has not made any change in the cookies.

What else shall I try?

## Underlying Motivation

Recorded a Web session and played it back.
Added a RegEx Extractor to pull out a token and then added it to subsequent requests.  That helped.
However, certain requests failed with an custom application exception `Security violation, please refresh`.
Probably session login state is not being passed, so the website thinks the call is "stale".
I've seen this on the GUI when the session expires and you try to click a button on the site.

On comparing the cookies seem in JMeter with what I saw in the Chrome Debugger, it was clear that there were more cookies in the running application than what I had in JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol because if you have `secure` flag and using HTTP protocol - the cookie will not be sent.

Also remove `=` from `partner=` otherwise you will end up with `partner==favicon.ico`

[image]

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Using HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)